# Reporting services 2008 reports connection to azure sql database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssrs

Due to the end of support of sql server 2008 R2 we are planning to move the database to azure as a paas service (azure sql database). Right now the application server has reporting services 2008 R2, for now it won't be moved to the cloud or upgrade his version. The users create the reports, then they upload them to reporting services and generate the desired information, My question is this: since azure sql database uses the latest version of sql server do the users or myself have to redo the reports in a newer version of report builder or visual studio data tools, or the reports will work the same way and the only thing I have to modify is the data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about migrating `ReportServer` and `ReportServerTempDB`.  As per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-report-server-create-a-report-server-database?view=sql-server-ver15), Azure SQL Database is not supported.  Below are the support databases

- Azure SQL Managed Instance
- SQL Server 2019
- SQL Server 2017
- SQL Server 2016 (13.x)
- SQL Server 2014 (12.x)
- SQL Server 2012 (11.x)
- SQL Server 2008 R2

I have done one Reporting Server migration and since we will be backup and restoring the reporting databases, the reports are migrated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases need to be able to communicate with each other, SQL Database is not a valid option.

However, if you migrate to SQL Server 2008 in an Azure VM and have Software Assurance then you may be able to get extended support and continue to use the 2008 version for an extended period.